# query on shell scripting

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following o/p,

```
2001:8888:5678:ddd2::32 via 2001:8888:5678:dde0::1 dev vlan3943
```

I want it to be converted like below,

```
2001:8888:5678:ddd2::32/128 via 2001:8888:5678:dde0::1 dev vlan3943
```

i.e. add "/128" after "2001:8888:5678:ddd2::32"

Comment: You have selected correct tools (`awk`, `sed`). What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple replacement with `sed` command:

```
line="2001:8888:5678:ddd2::32 via 2001:8888:5678:dde0::1 dev vlan3943" 
echo $line | sed -r 's/^(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}[0-9a-f]{1,4}::[0-9]+)/\1\/128/'
```

`-r` option, allows extended regular expresssions

`^(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}[0-9a-f]{1,4}::[0-9]+)` - will match IPv6 address at the start of your input string